# how to divide a variable by a number in python?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, math

i am building a python script for finding the ETA of files when uploading to the internet. I did the rough working the i tried doing it on python.
 Basically the program asks you to input the file size and the uploading speed. 
But i'm stuck!!

The script is this:.. (in progress)

```
print "UPLOADING TIME COVERTER"
print
print " Please enter the file size in mb"
size = raw_input()
# for e.g 237mb
print
print "Please enter the current uploading speed in kb /sec"
speed = raw_input()
# for e.g 60kb/sec
print
A = speed * 60
# speed is changed into minutes
B = (A / 1024)
#KB  is changed in MB
C = (B / size)
print "your eta is %r hours" %(C)`
```

The error I receive is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uploadingeta.py", line 14, in <module>
    B = (A - 1024)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'.
```

I searched google and everywhere but couldn't a solution.

Comment: `raw_input` returns a string. You need to convert it to an `int` or `float` before doing math with the value.

Comment: how do i do that? I'm a beginner at this. :(

Comment: size = int(raw_input())   -- please beware that this will throw an exception if the input cannot be converted to an int

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to do your parsing and reading.  Modify to suit.

```
import re

mb_match = re.compile(r'^([0-9])+[Mm][Bb]?$').match
kb_match = re.compile(r'^([0-9])+[Kk][Bb]?$').match
b_match = re.compile(r'^([0-9])+[Bb]?$').match

def parse_size(text):
  text = text.strip()
  match = mb_match(text)
  if match:
    return int(match.group(1)) * 1024 * 1024 

  match = kb_match(text)
  if match:
    return int(match.group(1)) * 1024

  match = b_match(text)
  if match:
    return int(match.group(1))

  raise ValueError('Invalid input')


while True:
  text = raw_input('Enter file size...')
  try:
    file_size_bytes = parse_input(raw_input('Enter file size: '))
    break
  except ValueError as e:
    print(e)

while True:
  text = raw_input('Enter upload speed size...')
  try:
    upload_speed = parse_input(raw_input('Enter file size: '))
    break
  except ValueError as e:
    print(e)

#file_size_bytes
#upload_speed
```

Comment: error in line 27

`NameError: name 'parse_input' is not defined.`

how do i define it?

Answer (score 0):

you can't divide a str and an int. you will have to cast it to an int such as

int(speed)

you can also add  code to your file for debuging such as

print(type(speed))

this will tell you the data type of the Variable which is useful for solving all sorts of problems.

Answer (score 0):

use
`speed = int(raw_input)`

The reason your code gives you an error is because when you use raw input, it records input as a string, so in this case you would have to cast it using int().

You probably already saw the other answers, but hopefully mine can explain a little about the problem.